# CentOS ls uses dpkg

Tags: centos, dpkg

I am logged in as a user on an CentOS version 6.9 HPC. When I try the `ls` command, I get:

> /usr/local/bin/ls: line 96: dpkg: command not found Abort, this script
> is only intended for Ubuntu-like distros

When I open the corresponding ls file, line 96 has the line:

```
# (internal) The architecture of the local system
arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)
```

I understand that dpkg is a Debian thing which is why it wouldn't work on CentOS. But why is the dpkg there in the first place. And how do I run a simple `ls`?

Comment: `CentOS version 6.9 HPC` - ask whoever created this version. It is seemingly modified for no obvious reasons. Maybe you've got malware, it's hard to say. Or maybe it's not CentOS at all. Who knows.

Comment: This is odd. Does the rest of the `ls` command script have anything to do with actually running `ls`, or is it trying to install software without you noticing?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your `ls` command seems to have been replaced by the following shell script: https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/blob/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh  Your system is broken and I would contact your administrator about this.

Comment: It's unclear why `/usr/local/bin` comes before standard directories like `/bin` and `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` variable.  What you could possibly try to do is to rearrange the variable's directories so that `/usr/local/bin` is either removed completely or down-prioritized.  The contents of `/usr/local/bin` seem messed up though.

Comment: Some more input from you would be nice to see. E.g., is your `/usr/local/bin/ls` actually the script that I found, are the other executables in the same directory (like, `cp`, `mv`, `rm`, etc.) likewise broken, does the brokenness extend into other directories under `/usr/local`, and is the immediate issue resolved by a local change to your shell's startup files (changing the ordering of the `PATH` variable)?

Comment: It works. I changed the contents of bashrc to add `/bin` at the beginning of the `PATH`. Can't thank you enough :)

Comment: It may work, but it still seems your system is broken. Unless you fix it, you will have problems in the future.

Comment: @Kusalananda _"It's unclear why /usr/local/bin comes before standard directories like /bin and /usr/bin in your PATH variable."_ - Because that's the default on most systems?

Comment: @Kusalananda it allows locally modified versions of standard tools to be found with no further involvement from users. If those locally modified versions are broken it's up to the system admin to fix or remove as appropriate

Comment: @ChrisDavies Shrug. It seems to have been an issue in this case. I would trust the tools in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` over whatever stuff someone put in `/usr/local/bin`, _especially_ with regards to base system utilities like `ls`. Putting `/usr/local/bin` before `/bin` and `/usr/bin` sounds like a recipe for strange and hard-to-track down bugs, even without errors like what this user had.

Comment: @marcelm Only because everyone's doing it doesn't mean it is correct. It also does not mean one can't change it.

Comment: @Kusalananda If you install a copy of program `foo` manually (and then into `/usr/local/bin`) that's probably because you want to use it. And if there was one provided by a package (in `/usr/bin`) then your version is probably _better_ in some aspect (usually a newer version, but it could e.g. be patched to work better in your system, etc.) Prioritizing `/usr/local/bin` means those programs are directly available instead of the packaged one, without needing to change the contents of `/usr/bin` at all. Of course, if sysadmin shouldn't put a broken binary, or one not following the contract...

Comment: Begin investigating by running: `rpm -q --what-provides /usr/local/bin/ls` to find which package installed that script. If none, then it was installed manually, and if you are the sysadmin, and didn't install it.. that's where I would begin to worry.

Comment: @Ángel I know how that is supposed to work, and I'm of the opinion that setting one's PATH to prioritise variants of base utilities that are "local" should be something that an individual user or script should do. It should not be a default.

Comment: @Kusalananda The fact that you think it's wrong (which is an opinion, not fact!) doesn't change that it's the standard. So, of course `/usr/local/bin` has higher precedence on OPs system, as it does on most systems. Your comment made it seem like the OPs system is anomalous, when it isn't. That doesn't mean your opinion is without merit; there are risks associated with that default precedence. But saying "it's unclear why" when it is in fact very clear why isn't very helpful.

Comment: @marcelm It was certainly unclear to me why any system would want to order `PATH` in that way, which is where my initial comment came from. You (all) have tried to explain the reasoning behind this, and I now understand that this is a common way of using `PATH`, but that does not convince me that it's correct. I'm not asking to be convinced either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the question text, it is evident that the `ls` command is picked up from the `/usr/local/bin` directory, which means that this directory is found earlier in the `PATH` variable's value than e.g. `/usr/bin` and `/bin`.

Changing the ordering of the variable's value in your shell's startup files, possibly by prepend `/bin` and `/usr/bin` to it, should stop your shell from using `ls` from `/usr/local/bin`, assuming that there is an `ls` command in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

```bash
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
```

The reason *why* `/usr/local/bin/ls` is a shell script (possibly a copy of [the Ubuntu-specific script found here](https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/blob/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh), which, although not malware, is not at all related to the `ls` command in any way) is still a mystery, as is whether this anomality is limited to the `ls` executable or whether it extends to other files and directories under `/usr/local`.